# PGF plots cuts the exponential multiplier

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats

If I run the code shown below, the exponential multiplier of the y-axis is slighly cut off. How do I fix this?

Thanks.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=7cm,
height=6cm,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
ylabel shift = -3.0 pt,
grid=major,
every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.7pt},
legend pos=north east,
legend entries={$test$},
xmin=0, xmax=2,
ymin=-0.00000006, ymax=0.00000001,
ytick={-0.00000006,-0.00000005,-0.00000004,-0.00000003,-0.00000002,-0.00000001,0,0.00000001},
]
\addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates { 
(0,-0.000000028559703) 
(1,-0.000000035301677)
(2,-0.000000043050655) 
(3,-0.000000051413136) 
(4,-0.000000060322865)
(5,-0.000000069675052)
(6,-0.000000079377747) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can increase the cropping area a small amount via `\standaloneconfig{border=0.5bp}`

Comment: or placing the `border` parameter in option of the `\documentclass` command: `\documentclass[border=.5bp]{standalone}`.

Comment: Axis option `title={\rule{0pt}{1pt}}` also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't `pgfplots`' fault at all. The character itself has a bounding box, and the glyph protrudes a little bit out of that box, as one can see from this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\fbox{$8$}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of above code]

The comments mentioned a couple of possible workarounds. Regarding the `border` option of `standalone`, one might mention that separate values can be set for each side, so to add 0.5pt only at the top, use

```
\documentclass[11pt,border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0.5pt}]{standalone}
```

The values are for left, right, bottom, and top, respectively.

Another alternative is to add

```
every y tick scale label/.append style={font=\strut}
```

to the `axis` options. This will effectively add a `\strut` in the node that contains the multiplier, which increases the text height a bit.

[image: output of code]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[11pt,convert]{standalone}
%\documentclass[11pt,border={0pt 0pt 0pt 0.5pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=7cm,
height=6cm,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
ylabel shift = -3.0 pt,
grid=major,
every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.7pt},
legend pos=north east,
legend entries={test},
xmin=0, xmax=2,
ymin=-0.00000006, ymax=0.00000001,
ytick={-0.00000006,-0.00000005,-0.00000004,-0.00000003,-0.00000002,-0.00000001,0,0.00000001},
every y tick scale label/.append style={font=\strut}
]
\addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates { 
(0,-0.000000028559703) 
(1,-0.000000035301677)
(2,-0.000000043050655) 
(3,-0.000000051413136) 
(4,-0.000000060322865)
(5,-0.000000069675052)
(6,-0.000000079377747) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```